# ASP MVC 3 DropDown list in Edit View

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3

Hi guys in new with asp mvc, so i having problem with the DropDown in edit view:

```
The ViewData item that has the key 'ProvinciaID' is of type 'System.Int32' but must be of type 'IEnumerable<SelectListItem>'.
```

## Provincia Model:

```
public class Provincia
    {
        public int ProvinciaID { get; set; }
        [DisplayName("Provincia")]
        [Required(ErrorMessage = "Provincia es requerida")]
        public string ProvinciaNombre { get; set; }
    }
```

## Registro Model:

```
public class Registro
    {
        public int ID { get; set; }
        ....

        [DisplayName("Provincia")]
        [Required]
        public int ProvinciaID { get; set; }
        public List<Provincia> rProvincia { get; set; }
        ....
}
```

## Controller

```
public ActionResult Edit(int id)
        {
            Registro registro = db.Registros.Find(id);

            ViewBag.provincias = new SelectList(db.Provincias, "ProvinciaID", "ProvinciaNombre", registro.ProvinciaID);            

            return View(registro);
        }
```

## View

```
<div class="editor-label">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.ProvinciaID)
        </div>
        <div class="editor-field">
            @Html.DropDownList("ProvinciaID", (IEnumerable<SelectListItem>)ViewData["provincias"]))
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.ProvinciaID)
        </div>
```

Any idea?

Thanks guys

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that you are using this Edit view (the one you showed in your question) in some other controller action and this other controller action doesn't set `ViewBag.provincias`. You must always set `ViewBag.provincias` if you want to use this view. I suppose that this other controller action is the one you are POSTing to the form:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Edit(Registro registro)
{
    if (!ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        // I guess that here you are trying to redisplay the Edit view
        // but you forgot to set ViewBag.provincias as you did in the
        // GET Edit action and an exception is thrown because the Edit view
        // always expects ViewBag.provincias to be set

        // So set it before returning to the same view:

        ViewBag.provincias = new SelectList(db.Provincias, "ProvinciaID", "ProvinciaNombre", registro.ProvinciaID);

        return View(registro);
    }
    return RedirectToAction("Success");
}
```